# How to cache an illustrated map?

Tags: image, caching, maps

A website has an illustrated map as a central feature, with waterfall like loading on the initial visit.  The goal is that the map shouldn't have to reload each time a user visits the page within a given session. How can we prevent the map from constantly reloading each time the user wants to navigate in a given session?

Link here:  http://thebambergergroup.com/map/murray-hill/nyc

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I'm understanding this question right... here goes!

The quick-and-dirty way would be to use a cookie to store a bit of state about whether or not the user has loaded the map yet, then use that to decide how the map should load (either waterfall fade in animations, or all at once)

So, when the image load is done (if you don't have a handle on when it's finished, either cheat and use a timer, or just assume that if the user has visited the page at all:

```js
//please don't actually do it this way, 
//there are many better libraries to handle cookies
//you'll also want to look at expiry time, etc
function loadImagesFinished(){
   document.cookie = 'mapLoaded=true';
}
```

Then, for when your page is loading and you want to decide how to load the images:

```js
var haveMapImagesBeenLoaded = getCookie('mapLoaded');
if (haveMapImagesBeenLoaded){
  loadImagesWaterfallAnimation();
} else {
  loadImagesAllAtOnce();
}
```

Obviously a lot of oversimplification happening, but you get the idea.

If you'd like a more robust way, you can use server-side session storage (if your language supports it, which it likely does). The general approach is still the same, though. Check if the session contains the mapLoaded attribute, if not, set it and write out something to indicate to the browser it needs to load the map with the waterfall animation (different HTML, a JS variable inside a `<script>` tag, an http response header, a cookie... anything!). Otherwise, load it all at once!